# unable to deploy django project on railway

Tags: django, railway.js

keep receiving 'stream did not contain valid UTF-8' at the building stage

tried using the pipreq command to generate requirements.txt in place of pip freeze>, yet it made no difference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same error. I am new to the world of Python, so my solution may not be quite right. I opened requirements.txt in notepad++ and changed the encoding manually (Encoding -> UTF-8)